# How to paginate when HTML preview is triggered in BIRT RCP?

Tags: pagination, rcp, birt

I've read [here](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/reportEngineAPI.php) that pagination is not possible when using `RunAndRenderTask`; it should be the separate `RunTask` and `RenderTask` to achieve this, correct?

Now, the thing is, we're using BIRT RCP and we cannot implement a separate WebViewer due to our requirements. While I was tracing, however, I noticed that the RCP app uses `RunAndRenderTask` when I preview the report as HTML. Also, the viewer used is `/preview`. If I understood [this](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerUsage2.2.php) right, for me to get the separated Run & Render tasks, I should be using `/frameset`.

So, my question is, for BIRT RCP, is there a way to paginate the HTML preview *without* implementing a separate WebViewer? In short, can I somehow force the base RCP to paginate the HTML in HTML preview? If so, how do I get to the separate Run & Render tasks or use `/frameset`? I'm not very knowledgeable about emitters and I'm still trying to understand how the HTML emitter was implemented.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it - set `/frameset` on the WebViewer class while the controls for the pagination are in  the report engine service.